# Mobile_WS_Controller not found

Tags: php

Hi in the below php file I am calling in my android application but I am tried in postman am getting the below error.Using this url am accessing the login page but it is not working .No response from app

can any one please help me

Login.php:

```
<?php
    class Mobile_WS_Login extends Mobile_WS_Controller {

        function requireLogin() {
            return false;
        }

        function process(Mobile_API_Request $request) {
            $response = new Mobile_API_Response();

            $username = $request->get('username');
            $password = $request->get('password');

            $current_user = CRMEntity::getInstance('Users');
            $current_user->column_fields['user_name'] = $username;

            if(vtlib_isModuleActive('Mobile') === false) {
                $response->setError(1501, 'Service not available');
                return $response;
            }

            if(!$current_user->doLogin($password)) {

                $response->setError(1210, 'Authentication Failed');

            } else {
                // Start session now
                $sessionid = Mobile_API_Session::init();

                if($sessionid === false) {
                    echo "Session init failed $sessionid\n";
                }

                $current_user->id = $current_user->retrieve_user_id($username);
                $current_user->retrieveCurrentUserInfoFromFile($current_user->id);
                $this->setActiveUser($current_user);

                $result = array();
                $result['login'] = array(
                    'userid' => $current_user->id,
                    'crm_tz' => DateTimeField::getDBTimeZone(),
                    'user_tz' => $current_user->time_zone,
                    'user_currency' => $current_user->currency_code,
                    'session'=> $sessionid,
                    'vtiger_version' => Mobile_WS_Utils::getVtigerVersion(),
                    'date_format' => $current_user->date_format,
                    'mobile_module_version' => Mobile_WS_Utils::getVersion()
                );
                $response->setResult($result);

                $this->postProcess($response);
            }
            return $response;
        }

        function postProcess(Mobile_API_Response $response) {
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

Postman:

URL:http://XXXXXXX/modules/mobile/api/ws/Login.php

```
parms: username:abc
       password:abc1
       operation:login
```

Response From Postman:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Mobile_WS_Controller' not found in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\crmtest\modules\Mobile\api\ws\Login.php</b> on line
<b>10</b>
<br />
```

Comment: Where are you including/loading the `Mobile_WS_Controller`-class?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't have that classs

Comment: Before you can extend a class, it must exist (and be included, either manually using `require` or using auto loading). Now you're telling PHP to create a new class based on a non-existing class, which won't work.